# Windows specific CSS selector or code snippet

Tags: php, html, css, linux, windows

I am developing a website in PHP under *Ubuntu*, and I just begun testing it under cross-platform environments. I noticed, that some **CSS** rules, does not look the same under *Windows* (maybe due to it's font rendering method), so I decided to optimize my **CSS** code to work properly on *Windows* too. I don't want to loose the current look under other operating systems, so the simple code replacement is not a solution. I'am looking for some **CSS selector**, like browser selectors but for operating systems, especially for *Windows*. Is it possible, or I need to do this with multiple CSS files, or with some javascript? I want to keep the content SEO friendly as well. Thank you for reading!

*EDIT:* I use @font-face on this website. The items I have problem with, use these fonts.

The site looks the same in every browser under *Ubuntu*. The problems are under *Windows*.

Comment: I think you first need to make a very important distinction. It's NOT the OS, which renders your website. It's your browser. The worst thing your OS can do to your website is not having the font you work with.

Comment: You need to give details on the error.  It is more likely that there is an issue with the browser than with the OS.

Comment: I'am using @font-face, so that is why I think the problem is text rendering differences. I already optimized the fonts and added hinting.

Answer (score 0):

No, it is impossible with pure CSS.
Here is an interesting walkaround http://rafael.adm.br/css_browser_selector/ .

Answer (score 0):

There are no CSS selectors for operating systems, only for the browser. You'll need to use JS to detect the OS and base your CSS off of that - like:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

var mactest=navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Mac")!=-1 //Logic test for OS

var mac_css='/style/macstyle.css' //mac css
var pc_css='/style/pcstyle.css'   //pc css

document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="'+ (mactest? mac_externalcss : pc_externalcss) +'">')

</script>
```